# Mganeto2: doesn't exist or not a file .js

Tags: magento2, javascript

In exception log file I get every time issue:

```
[2018-08-26 10:41:56] main.CRITICAL: The path "/home/czasowe/domains/domain.com/public_html/var/tmp/_cache/merged/dff080226ea3597444c03925cb09364e.js" cannot be renamed into "/home/czasowe/domains/domain.com/public_html/pub/static/_cache/merged/dff080226ea3597444c03925cb09364e.js" Warning!rename(/home/czasowe/domains/domain.com/public_html/var/tmp/_cache/merged/dff080226ea3597444c03925cb09364e.js,/home/czasowe/domains/domain.com/public_html/pub/static/_cache/merged/dff080226ea3597444c03925cb09364e.js): No such file or directory {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\FileSystemException(code: 0): The path \"/home/czasowe/domains/domain.com/public_html/var/tmp/_cache/merged/dff080226ea3597444c03925cb09364e.js\" cannot be renamed into \"/home/czasowe/domains/domain.com/public_html/pub/static/_cache/merged/dff080226ea3597444c03925cb09364e.js\" Warning!rename(/home/czasowe/domains/domain.com/public_html/var/tmp/_cache/merged/dff080226ea3597444c03925cb09364e.js,/home/czasowe/domains/domain.com/public_html/pub/static/_cache/merged/dff080226ea3597444c03925cb09364e.js): No such file or directory at /home/czasowe/domains/domain.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Filesystem/Driver/File.php:298)"} []
[2018-08-26 10:43:17] main.CRITICAL: The file "/home/czasowe/domains/domain.com/public_html/var/tmp/_cache/merged/dff080226ea3597444c03925cb09364e.js" doesn't exist or not a file {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\FileSystemException(code: 0): The file \"/home/czasowe/domains/domain.com/public_html/var/tmp/_cache/merged/dff080226ea3597444c03925cb09364e.js\" doesn't exist or not a file at /home/czasowe/domains/domain.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Filesystem/Directory/Write.php:70)"} []
```

Anyone know how to solve this issue?

Comment: have you try deploy?  bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Comment: Yes, I have try deploy and still issue.

Comment: try to reset server premission correctly?

Comment: Hey, did you solve your problem?